# Nginx Redirect allsubdomains to a non-subdomain url

Tags: https, redirection, nginx, url, subdomain

I am currently issueing the following problem and by hell, i can't solve it. The > 20 similar threads i found with google are no help.

First of all, i created a simple HTTP to HTTPS redirect, which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    return 301 https://my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    ...
}
```

And this works perfectly fine. If i try to open *my-domain.com*, i will get redirected to *https:// my-domain.com*. But there is still the issue with subdomains. If i open *www.my-domain.com* or *test.my-domain.com*, i would like these subdomains to redirect to my root *HTTPS* domain: https:// my-domain.com. Without any subdomains in front of it. The same should appear for HTTPS subdomains. I literally want to ban any subdomains (for now).

I have tried a lot of configurations, like adding **.my-domain.com* to the server_name, and still this doesn't work as expected. I also tried to create a HTTPS redirect from *.my-domain.com to my normal HTTPS domain, and still i have a similar result with each configuration:

1. All HTTP requests result in a HTTPS url containing the subdomain.
2. All HTTPS requests never result in a HTTPS url WITHOUT a subdomain in it.

Now my Question: How can i redirect every subdomain(http and https) to a specific https URL containing NO subdomain in it? Every combination should always result in: *https:// my-domain.com$request_uri*

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Didn't solve my issue fully, but i have something i can live with. I created a CNAME from www.my-domain.com to my-domain.com in my domain configuration. I also modified nginx and added a new server configuration which redirects from 443 www.my-domain to https:// my-domain. i also have a normal port 80 server which redirects also from www.my-domain to https:// my-domain. I modified my certificate and added www.my-domain to the list of domains and subdomains. Now every request on www.my-domain(http or https) will redirect to https://my-domain. Also my-domain(http and without www.) will redirect to https://my-domain too. This seems "okay" for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `default_server` block to match any `http` and `https` domains not explicitly defined in another `server` block. The `https` part only works properly with wild-card certificates.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ... ssl configuration
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server) for details.